# before_filter with exception for current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authentication, filtering, before-filter

I have this current before filter in my users_controller

```
before_filter :authenticate_usergroup, :except => [:edit, :update, :show]
```

It works great for just allowing a user to edit their information but not being able to see all the users, but i'v found that by just changing their 'id' in the url they could also edit other users information.

How can i only allow :edit, :show and :update functions to the current user for their own record. i have this method in my application_controller to be able to access the current user

```
def current_user
 return unless session[:user_id]
 @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
end

#update from users_controller.rb
def update
@user = User.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    format.html { redirect_to @user, :notice => 'User was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "edit" }
    format.json { render :json => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

Comment: Show us one of your actions so we can give you an answer with better context.

Comment: @Deefour i will add my update action (i think thats what you are asking), i apolagise i'm quite new to ruby on rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you "scope" that only the `current_user` can access their information, then it doesn't matter.

so in show and edit

`@user = current_user`

in update action something like 
`current_user.update_attributes(params[:user])`
should do the trick.

Comment: i have it so that admins can update anybodies information. would this still allow that?

Comment: thankyou, i used your idea and put it inside an if statement that checked the group of the member logged in, and used a different @user if the group was admin.

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way:

in #show action in the controller:

```
if current_user.id == Certificate.find(params[:id]).user_id
  @certificate = Certificate.find(params[:id])
else
  redirect_to certificates_url, notice: 'You can only view your own certificates'
end
```

I know its not using a 'before_filter', but it seems to have the same effect of blocking users from simply typing in different urls to view other users information.